# How to use random kitchen sinks for $\sigma \neq 1$?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, random-fourier-features

The RBF kernel is given by
$$
k(x,y) = \exp\left(-\frac{\| x - y \|_2^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right)
$$

where $\sigma$ is the length-scale parameter. I want to use the random kitchen sinks method to create a basis that approximates this kernel with parameter $\sigma > 0$.

The random kitchen sinks basis is given by
$$
Z = \sqrt{\frac{2}{D}}\cos(XW + b)
$$
where $W$ and $b$ are drawn from specific distributions, depending on what kernel you're approximating. $D$ is the number of basis vectors you're using. The matrix $W$ has dimension $p \times D$ where $p$ is the number of features in $X$ and $b\sim \text{Uniform}[0,2\pi)$ is a vector of $D$ elements.

The random kitchen sinks basis approximates the kernel matrix $K$ in the sense that
$
K \approx ZZ^\top
$. Rahimi & Recht's papers show the specific sense that this is an approximation.

All of the discussion and explanations that I've read start from the description that you draw weights $w \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, but obviously this assumes you're setting $\sigma=1$. But it's well-known that the fit of a kernel method strongly depends on the length scale parameter. So what distribution do I use for a specific value of $\sigma$?

Comment: you could just do $\mathbf{X} \gets \frac{\mathbf{X}}{\sigma}$ and then proceed as usual

Comment: @JohnMadden's comment is equivalent to $w \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^{-2})$ -- the inverse Fourier transform of the Gaussian density.

Comment: By default, $\sigma$ is typically taken as the smallest between cluster distance.